# Regex finds substring

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I have a list of strings that look liked this

```
"Heartbeats::hype-wss://vps-gb2.nsa.drw:7026"
"Heartbeats::hype-wss://vps-de7.nsa.drw:7026"
"Heartbeats::hype-wss://vps-gb3.nsa.drw:7006"
"Heartbeats::hype-wss://vps-de2.nsa.drw:7043"
"Heartbeats::hype-wss://vps-jp2.nsa.drw:7060"
"Heartbeats::hype-wss://vps-jp2.nsa.drw:7071"
"Heartbeats::hype-wss://vps-de3.nsa.drw:7055"
"Heartbeats::hype-wss://vps-de3.nsa.drw:7066"
"Heartbeats::hype-wss://vps-gb2.nsa.drw:7005"
```

I would like to get the substrings `gb2`, `de7`, `gb3` etc that are after `vps-` and also the four digit numbers at the end. Is there a clean way to do this in regex?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `/\/{2}\w+-(\w{3})|(\d+$)/` and access the groups.

Comment: Have a look here https://regex101.com/. In general, do some research and try a few things before you ask for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using those samples, this is an alternative `/(\w+\d)/g`

**Explanation:** https://regex101.com/r/64MOHt/1

```js
console.log("Heartbeats::hype-wss://vps-gb2.nsa.drw:7026".match(/(\w+\d)/g))
console.log("Heartbeats::hype-wss://vps-de7.nsa.drw:7026".match(/(\w+\d)/g))
console.log("Heartbeats::hype-wss://vps-gb3.nsa.drw:7006".match(/(\w+\d)/g))
console.log("Heartbeats::hype-wss://vps-de2.nsa.drw:7043".match(/(\w+\d)/g))
console.log("Heartbeats::hype-wss://vps-jp2.nsa.drw:7060".match(/(\w+\d)/g))
console.log("Heartbeats::hype-wss://vps-jp2.nsa.drw:7071".match(/(\w+\d)/g))
console.log("Heartbeats::hype-wss://vps-de3.nsa.drw:7055".match(/(\w+\d)/g))
console.log("Heartbeats::hype-wss://vps-de3.nsa.drw:7066".match(/(\w+\d)/g))
console.log("Heartbeats::hype-wss://vps-gb2.nsa.drw:7005".match(/(\w+\d)/g))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: So simple... Amazing solution. I definitely overthought it.

Comment: Just as a small sidenote, `.aaa.ZZZ:` without any number is a must have - otherwise it could break (like i.e: `Heartbeats::hype-wss://vps-gb2.n3a.drw:7026`)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes, cause that I said *Using those samples*

Comment: @Ele Is there a way to catch `test` if the string does not have `vps-` prefix? ie `Heartbeats::hype-wss://test.nsa.drw:8558`

Answer (score 0):

You can easily do like:

```
vps-([^.]+)
```

which means:

- After `vps-`
- `(` match
- `[^.]` anything that is not a dot
- `+` one or more times

For the number at the end you can than expand with:

```
vps-([^.]+).*:(\d+)$
```

- `.*` any character 0 or more times until...
- `:` column and...
- `(\d+)` Match one or more integers
- `$` followed by end of string

Comment: Only answers half the question.

Comment: This doesn't address all of OP's requirements

Answer (score 0):

This can work for you:

```
.*vps-([^.]*)[^:]*:(\d*)
```

You must get the group[0] and group[1].

You can test it here:

https://regex101.com/#javascript